# How to create a new array from array's key value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need an efficient way to convert this array:

```
[
    {
      uuid: 1,
      date: '2020-12-25',
      note: 'example note 1',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['english']
    },
    {
      uuid: 2,
      date: '2020-12-25',
      note: 'example note 2',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['french']
    },
    {
      uuid: 3,
      date: '2020-12-26',
      note: 'example note 3',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['spanish']
    },
    {
      uuid: 4,
      date: '2020-12-26',
      note: 'example note 4',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['chinese']
    },
  ]
```

to this new array grouped by date

```
[
    {
    date:'2020-12-26',
    details:[
      {
        uuid: 3,
        date: '2020-12-26',
        note: 'example note 3',
        time: '12:05:00',
        language: ['spanish']
      },
      {
        uuid: 4,
        date: '2020-12-26',
        note: 'example note 4',
        time: '12:05:00',
        language: ['chinese']
      },
    ]
  },
    {
    date:'2020-12-25',
    details:[
      {
        uuid: 1,
        date: '2020-12-26',
        note: 'example note 1',
        time: '12:05:00',
        language: ['english']
      },
      {
        uuid: 2,
        date: '2020-12-26',
        note: 'example note 2',
        time: '12:05:00',
        language: ['french']
      },
    ]
  },
  ]
```

i have tried it using lodash _.groupBy but that is not what i want my array to look like, i tried doing this combining, .filter , .reduce and .map but it is really lengthy and does not look efficient at all

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as:

```js
const data = [{ uuid: 1,date: '2020-12-25',note: 'example note 1',time: '12:05:00',language: ['english']},{uuid: 2,date: '2020-12-25',note: 'example note 2',time: '12:05:00',language: ['french']},{uuid: 3,date: '2020-12-26',note: 'example note 3',time: '12:05:00',language: ['spanish']}, {uuid: 4,date: '2020-12-26',note: 'example note 4',time: '12:05:00',language: ['chinese']},]

const result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.date === c.date);
  const elem = { uuid: c.uuid, note: c.note, time: c.time, language: c.language };

  if (found) {
    found.details.push(elem);
  } else {
    a.push({
      date: c.date,
      details: [elem]
    });
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `Map` is [way better](https://jsbench.me/bmke2t4o1b/1) optimized for lookups than `Array` + `.find()` when input dataset is large enough and data variance is relatively high

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` function to create groups and assign the values to them:

```js
const input = [
    {
      uuid: 1,
      date: '2020-12-25',
      note: 'example note 1',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['english']
    },
    {
      uuid: 2,
      date: '2020-12-25',
      note: 'example note 2',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['french']
    },
    {
      uuid: 3,
      date: '2020-12-26',
      note: 'example note 3',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['spanish']
    },
    {
      uuid: 4,
      date: '2020-12-26',
      note: 'example note 4',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['chinese']
    },
  ];
  
const output = input.reduce((result, record) => {
  if (!result[record.date]) result[record.date] = { date: record.date, details: [] };
  result[record.date].details.push(record);
  
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(output);

// If you want it as an array
console.log(Object.values(output));
```

Instead of creating it directly as an array, I create it as an object with the date as the key. This makes it so I don't have to search all of the results for the correct one.

I start by looking if I have an entry for that date. If I don't, I make one.

Then I simply add the record to the details for that entry.

At the end, I convert it to an array if you really need it that way simply by using `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could do a lodash `chain`, then a `groupBy` follewed by a `map`. Like this:

```js
let input = [
    {
      uuid: 1,
      date: '2020-12-25',
      note: 'example note 1',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['english']
    },
    {
      uuid: 2,
      date: '2020-12-25',
      note: 'example note 2',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['french']
    },
    {
      uuid: 3,
      date: '2020-12-26',
      note: 'example note 3',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['spanish']
    },
    {
      uuid: 4,
      date: '2020-12-26',
      note: 'example note 4',
      time: '12:05:00',
      language: ['chinese']
    },
  ]
  
  console.log(
  _.chain(input)
    // Group the elements of Array based on `date` property
    .groupBy("date")
    .map((value, key) => ({ date: key, details: value }))
    .value()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9p1fx3dq/1/

```
    var a = [
        {
          uuid: 1,
          date: '2020-12-25',
          note: 'example note 1',
          time: '12:05:00',
          language: ['english']
        },
        {
          uuid: 2,
          date: '2020-12-25',
          note: 'example note 2',
          time: '12:05:00',
          language: ['french']
        },
        {
          uuid: 3,
          date: '2020-12-26',
          note: 'example note 3',
          time: '12:05:00',
          language: ['spanish']
        },
        {
          uuid: 4,
          date: '2020-12-26',
          note: 'example note 4',
          time: '12:05:00',
          language: ['chinese']
        },
      ];
      
      function groupBy(key) {
      return function group(array) {
        return array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
          const property = obj[key];
          if (!acc.some(s => s.date === property)){
            acc.push({date: property, details: []});
          }
          var details = acc.find(s => s.date === property).details;
          details.push(obj);
          return acc;
        }, []);
      };
    }
    
    console.log(groupBy('date')(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `new Set` to get the distinct values

```
const array1 = [
  {
    uuid: 1,
    date: "2020-12-25",
    note: "example note 1",
    time: "12:05:00",
    language: ["english"]
  },
  {
    uuid: 2,
    date: "2020-12-25",
    note: "example note 2",
    time: "12:05:00",
    language: ["french"]
  },
  {
    uuid: 3,
    date: "2020-12-26",
    note: "example note 3",
    time: "12:05:00",
    language: ["spanish"]
  },
  {
    uuid: 4,
    date: "2020-12-26",
    note: "example note 4",
    time: "12:05:00",
    language: ["chinese"]
  }
];

const dates = array1.map(x => x.date);
const uniqueDates = [...new Set(dates)];
const result = uniqueDates.map(date => {
  return {
    date: date,
    details: array1.filter(f => f.date === date)
  }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be [inefficient way](https://jsbench.me/bmke2t4o1b/1) to achieve the desired result, since you loop source array once to extract dates, than you loop through unique dates array (which may be relatively large if data variance is high) with nested `.filter()`'s (looping the entire source array upon each iteration of `.map()`).

Comment: Great site, thank you. 

Yes, I know I did a double iteration, and the complexity of the algorithm is high, but I it is was the 2nd best solution in the benchmark, and in my opinion, the cleaner (if you don't have a lot of data)